# How to launch Lunar Client without internet connection?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Getting into Lunar Client's launcher needs internet connection, but when you enter the game, it works fine even offline if you've logged in at past.

My question is: Is there a way to bypass the initial launcher process and run the game directly, or just make it not require internet connection?

Comment: Again (because this happens occasionally), this is **not a technical problem with modded Minecraft**. The OP is trying to bypass the launcher, so they don't have to go online.

Comment: @Joachim you'll need to be logged in with Microsoft Account anyways, but when you're logged in, you're session details is stored for a while, just like how original launcher works. Just to say that I don't want to "Pirate" the game or anything, because you have to be logged in with a legit account anyways.